# how to change image button image when we click on button in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have one image button in Silverlight 
in initial load it will show `demo1` image, whenever I click on that button i should change image to `demo2`.

```
<Button x:Name="demo"
        IsEnabled="False"
        Click="demo_Click"
        ToolTipService.ToolTip="demo"
        Width="25"
        Height="25"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="0,0,0,25">

    <Image x:Name="demo-image" Source="/demo.content;component/demo1.png"/>

</Button>
```

Comment: You may also want to change "demo-image" to "demo_image"... minus signs are a really bad idea for element names :)

Comment: @dinesh Any success with the proposed solution below? In that case I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer, alternatively provide a comment explaining why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove `IsEnabled="False"` from the `Button` XAML. Then simply implement the `demo_Click` event handler in your code-behind as follows:

```
private void demo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    demo_image.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("/demo.content;component/demo2.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead